# How to run lynx Automate Browsing Actions in background

Tags: lynx

I am trying to extract some contents from one of my website for my report works.

I am unable to continue session in lynx.

So I am using an automate browser action script to login and print the page to a file and I am using that file to get my report.

But whenever, I run the script, it shows the browser actions in foreground. I dont want this and I would like to mute. i.e I dont want to see the browser action.

I am using the following method to run automate script.

```
lynx -cmd_log=/tmp/newscript http://example.com
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

lynx -cmd_script=/tmp/newscript http://example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I Found out the answer for this question.

We can modify the line to the given below line to make it silent.

lynx -cmd_script=/tmp/newscript http://example.com > /dev/null

Thank you all.